# Payment Gateway pay my customer through API

Tags: api, paypal, payment-gateway

I want to be able to give back money to my customers from a website, like for example if they get x amount of points they can exchange to real money.

Like you do when you send money to someone from Paypal

Is it possible from some Payment gateway provider? and if yes who is please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the PayPal's MassPay API : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/gs_MassPay/

This allow you to send money from your paypal account to recipients programatically.